# SQL Server Query Optimizing - WHERE clause vs SELECT subquery

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

When creating a query that joins 2 tables. I thought of 2 possible ways to write the query.
Below is a simplified example. Could you please let me know which would be faster?

```
SELECT t1.a,
       t2.a
FROM   table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.b = t2.b
WHERE  t2.c = 'test'
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.a,
       t2.a
FROM   table1 t1
       JOIN (SELECT a, b
             FROM   table2
             WHERE  c = 'test') t2
         ON t1.b = t2.b
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding `b` to the select list of the derived table because as @podiluska points out without it the second one wouldn't even compile making the whole question pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They should give exactly the same plan.

SQL Server will easily transform one to the other. Checking the execution plan is the only way to know for sure though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data, and your data structures.

You can find out for yourself by using the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option on the Query menu in SSMS.

I would say the first option is clearer though.

*Additionally, the second query as written won't actually work.*

Comment: RE: "It depends". Can you provide any case where the plans would not be the same?

Comment: No, but can you *prove* that they will always be the same?

Comment: No of course not. Because that would require me to exhaustively test infinite amounts of queries. I wondered if you had come across a case where it did in fact depend.

Comment: For the two forms written, they will always be the same. Tables are commutative between FROM/JOIN clauses even from inner to outer queries in this simple form, as are conditions commutative between ON, WHERE, AND.

Answer (score 0):

if you have proper indexes on table1.id and table2.id columns then I think the first query will perform better.